# arcore positional tracking in aframe?

Tags: aframe, arcore

Hi I'm new here and I want to make a WebAR application using A-Frame. I know the basics and all that but one major problem I'm having is being able to walk around in the scene using ARCore running in Chrome. Is this even possible? I found a WebVR application from 6 years ago that solved the problem of positional tracking but the code's so depreciated it doesn't work anymore. I would prefer using ARCore for tracking but if nothing else marker based tracking will work too.

Edit: here's the depreciated code on github https://github.com/AVGP/goggle-paper
Doesn't use ARCore but instead marker based tracking. Better than nothing I suppose.

Comment: Could you still provide the deprecated code? Coming from nothing its a bit hard to help.

Comment: Just edited OP to include link to depreciated code

Answer (score 0):

As of today, support for ARCore via the web (and thus A-Frame) is only available on Chrome browser with some Android devices.

Here are some great examples of working projects that you can build from:

https://github.com/chenzlabs/aframe-ar

https://aframe-ar.glitch.me/

---

New features such as image tracking are only available on Chrome Canary (experimental). See this example for image marker tracking:
https://arimg.glitch.me/

And associated documentation:
https://github.com/immersive-web/marker-tracking/blob/main/explainer.md